# Index-Match function with NOT EQUAL criteria

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to use the index with match function to give me the order of people based on their rankings. My data is something like this:

```
     A         B          C        
1   Rank     Name      Score                   
2 
3    1        Joe        100%                    
4    3        Bob        80%
5    1        John       100%
6    2        Dan        90%
7
8   RankOrder Name
9    1        =index(b3:b6,match(1,a3:a6,-1))    Result = Joe
10   1        =index(b3:b6,match(1&<>"b9",a3:a6,-1))   Result = John  **HELP 
11   2        =index(b3:b6,match(1&<>"b9&b10",a3:a6,-1)) Result = Dan **HELP
```

The first formula is to find who has a ranking of 1 or greater, then the second and third formula is where I'm struggling. I need to find who the has the next ranking closest to 1 but has not already been outputted in cell B9. Then the next formula would be the same but not someone that's been outputted in cell B9 & B10. Hopefully this make sense.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use index and aggregate with countif for aggregate's *k* factor.

```
=INDEX(B$1:B$6,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($3:$6)/(A$3:A$6=A9),COUNTIF(A$9:A9,A9)))
```

[image]

Comment: Forgot to mentioned that the RankOrder numbers will also be formulated to some kind of index/match or rearrange to the right side of the names for a vlookup to get the rank numbers. The most important is to get the names in the correct order first.

Comment: That's okay. I forgot to do anything about it anyways.

Comment: Sorry I didn't clarify this, but what I'm saying is that the code (A$3:A$6=A9) or COUNTIF(A$9:A9,A9) would not work, since I would not have anything in those cells until I get the names then I would do a vlookup or index/match to get the ranking numbers. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Why wouldn't you simply use RANK or SMALL or COUNTIF to get the same result?

Comment: The results in A3 to A6 is a result of RANK but it does display with rank and names in sequential order. I'm trying to get A9:B12 to display ranks and names in sequential order from 1st to 4th. I have not tried SMALL but could not get COUNTIF to work properly.